# Right-to-left interlinear translation, multiple words for one translation

Tags: xetex, linguistics, right-to-left, expex

I'm using ExPex for an interlinear translation in Hebrew. I'm having issues when translating one Hebrew word with multiple English words: the English words are right-to-left, while they should be left-to-right. See the example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\englishfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Latin Modern Roman}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Ezra SIL}
\usepackage{expex}

\begin{document}

\begin{hebrew}
\ex[everyglc=\englishfont] \begingl
\gla 7225 1254 430 853 8064 853 776//
\glb בְּרֵאשִׁ֖ית בָּרָ֣א אֱלֹהִ֑ים אֵ֥ת הַשָּׁמַ֖יִם וְאֵ֥ת הָאָֽרֶץ׃ //
\glc {In the beginning} created God - {the heavens} and {the earth.}//
\endgl\xe
\end{hebrew}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This should read:

```
the earth. and the heavens - God created In the beginning
```

How do I make that happen in a neat way?

Comment: When I compile your example, the English words are LTR as you want them.

Comment: If I remove the `everyglc=\englishfont` then the text comes out RTL.  Are you sure in your actual document you have specified `\englishfont` for `everyglc`?

Comment: So this might be a version related issue. @Camil: try updating your TeX distribution.

Comment: @AlanMunn this is my actual document for the time being :) but that's strange, that it's working for you. What version are you using? I have `XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99992 (TeX Live 2015/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=xelatex)`. All my packages are up to date.

Comment: This is somehow font-related.   I changed the fonts in my initial test, since I didn't have your fonts available. Using  used David CLM and Times the problem doesn't arise, but using Linux Libertine instead of Times, I can now reproduce the problem. It's not obviously version related, since I get no difference with TL 2014 or TL 2015.

Comment: @AlanMunn that's strange. When I try with Times New Roman and David CLM I have the same problem still (both Liberation Serif and the real Times New Roman from ttf-mscorefonts-installer). I also tried on a different machine (Ubuntu 14, TL 2013) with the same results...

Comment: BTW, there is a superfluous ת״ו in ‘תהָאָֽרֶץ’.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## An explicit (=cumbersome) and cleaner solution

A quick solution would be to use the [`bidi`](http://ctan.org/pkg/bidi) package’s `\LR{}` command:

```
\glc \LR{In the beginning} created God - \LR{the heavens} and \LR{the earth.}//
```

See §1.8 (Typesetting Short LTR and RTL Texts) in the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/xetex/latex/bidi/bidi.pdf) for further information.

## A somewhat easier to use solution

Add `\beginL` to the `everyglc` hook. This can be done locally (changing `\ex[everyglc=\englishfont]` to `\ex[everyglc=\englishfont\beginL]` in the question) or globally, by using the `\lingset` command like this:

```
\lingset{everyglc=\englishfont\beginL}
```

The downside of this solution is that it uses an internal macro of `bidi`; I’m not sure how risky it is to use this, but it seems like a good hack to me and I don’t think it is going to break easily soon (not unless radical changes will be made in `bidi` or `expex`).

Comment: Thank you, but I was hoping for a solution where I wouldn't have to type that every time. Do you happen to have that as well? :)

Comment: :-). I tried to use the `\begingl` option `everyglc=\setLR`, but it didn’t work.

Comment: I tried that too, and it didn't work; I'm not quite sure why.

Comment: @Alan Munn: I guess because `\setLR` sets the direction of a paragraph, not of a segment within a paragraph.

Comment: @CamilStaps — I’ve just added another solution which I think solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you, I can confirm that both options work. Excellent!

Comment: I’m happy it works for you :-)